# Border shown in Android Studio but not on a real device

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I'm having a strange issue. I'm using the following code for the background of my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#23000000" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

In Android Studio it looks like this

[image: PC]

But on a real device no border is shown whatsoever.

[image: real device]

At first I thought that the colors may be too simillar, so I used black as a border color, but same result occurs.

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/jobBox_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@null">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jobBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_shape"
        android:minHeight="100dp">

...
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try increasing the size of border first.

Comment: I tried with 5dp and 10dp and still the same result @piyush

Comment: for the sake of doing just try 25dp once as you have given padding 10dp to parent layout then tell.

Comment: Tried it as well, and still the same result

Comment: based on your screenshots, i think Android Studio is wrong, the screens look to different (no space between toolbar and content, background is white not grey), also you are using the 20 API, choose the same as on phone, also aktive the borders on phone in developer settings to see where the elements are... and try to just change it for phone not for the preview

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO I'm running Kitkat on my real device. Switching to API 19 shows the same layout (including the border), while on real device border is not shown. Background is different on a real device because it's using android:windowBackground to light gray. Also, the top padding is added on runtime for the first item. I'm confused, what else can I try? I know one other way but it would cause too much GPU overdraw.

Comment: maybe because the root view background have the same color as your border, try with the red in border to see if am i right

Comment: Tried it just now, (ff0000) and still not showing. Tried with 2dp width and with 30dp (as suggested in a comment before), same results.

Comment: Did not see an Answer on this page. So replying here - I am not sure why Android studio is showing the line. But I found a solution that works . Just add a style with the border and assign it to the layout. It works both in Studio and Real device.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some sort of bug with Android Studio. Although I changed the drawable XML, the old one (and I still haven't figured it out from where) was still being used. I checked if I had any duplicate files in my drawables, but I found out. Invalidate cache and restart didn't fix this issue neither.

So to fix this, a simple Refactor>Rename will suffice.